# C client-server application and battery saving on linux

Tags: c, linux, networking, battery-saver

Could someone explain me please, how i can achieve the most efficient battery saving: I want to code a simple client-server app. Server sending periodic messages to client (let's say 'hello'), and client just showing it. What will happen exactly in case client call poll / select and wait for incoming message? Will i waist resources on net ( 4g / wi-fi)? Or app should sleep and awake just sometimes to check for updates? May be some other solutions?

Comment: I doubt something simple like that will use much energy...on the network side, showing the message might cost some trivial amount...

Answer (score 0):

Calling `select` or `poll` doesn't use any significant resources. There's no looping, the process is simply blocked until the condition it's waiting for occurs. If you specify a timeout, it will only run that often.